# How can I convert all columns that have date values but have object datatype, to date datatype?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime, select

I have multiple columns in my df dataframe which contain dates (`yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00`) but are in object format. I want to convert all columns with such structure to Date only.

Comment: Can you add a [mre] with something you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

you may use `pd.to_datetime(...)`

ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html